# How to programatically retrieve all ant matcher URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a basic Spring application that has various endpoints, and a login page, defined by configuring the HttpSecurity of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

I have a service that looks for all of the endpoints within my aplication and collects some basic information about them, which I acheived by autowiring the RequestMappingHandlerMapping class and iterating through the different handler methods.

I would like to collect some similar information for the paths that are defined by the WebSecurityCongigurer adapter.

For example, within the configue method, if I have, say:

```java
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
```

From within the service I would like to collect the information: `"/login"` and `HttpMethod.POST`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My post doesn't directly answer the question since I am not aware of a way to do that. However, there is a workaround and this idea deserves a chance:

I recommend you to have a source of mappings and set `antMatchers` dynamically. This solution both configures the adapter and leaves the source of mappings available for further use (I recommend keeping the values themselves immutable).

```
List<MatcherMapping> mappings = ....
for (MatcherMapping mapping: mappings) {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers(mapping.getHttpMethod(), mapping.getUrl())
              .permitAll()
}
```

The class `MatcherMapping` would be just a simple data container.

```
public final class MatcherMapping {

    private final HttpMethod httpMethod;
    private final String url;

    // constructor and getters
}
```

Whether you get the data using a service or getting them directly doesn't matter is finally up to you.

Comment: Nice solution for a configurable adapter but not really what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway though!